# why @RestController by default use singleton scope?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, ejb

I am actually a EJB developer and very new in spring framework.

i find a couples of conflict conceptually. Like ..
@RestController use by default scope which is singleton. By single object per loc have to manage heavy trafic.

is it a good design?

Comment: Why not. A single instance is perfectly capable of handling lots of requests. One thing to take care of is to not store state inside a singleton, apart from that it works fine.

Comment: for concurrent request how single instance will perform?

Comment: It will perform perfectly fine. It doesn't matter if that object is used by 1 or 100 threads.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, it is a good design because the same instance of the object will be reused instead of keep creating it each time you need it. That is the whole point of that design pattern.
Here is a great example where singleton comes to the rescue.

https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-2119

By default, spring will take care of the creation and destruction of all singleton beans, while the prototype has to be manually handled. Therefore in a lot of cases prototype scope is for custom beans made by developers.

[In SpringMVC Controller layer, @Scope("prototype") vs @Scope("singleton")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148094/in-springmvc-controller-layer-scopeprototype-vs-scopesingleton)

Answer (score 0):

> is it a good design?

Yes, all beans in Spring are singletons (by default).

We have 100+ controllers in several applications and it works perfectly.

If you really need to instantiate controllers more than once, you can, of course, consider other bean scopes (see brief explanation of scopes here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes)